# IPTables: apt-get and wget not working

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall, apt, wget

When resetting IPTables, the apt-get and wget command functions correctly and also downloads what I want. But once I activate this firewall, it isn't functional. Pings still work.

I want to allow all outgoing connections. That's why I added "iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT" at the end.

IPTables Firewall:
http://pastebin.com/pTGyiz7c

iptables -L -n -v: http://pastebin.com/6Q8Mbgfh

Comment: OK But what is really in iptables ? Could you add the result of "iptables -L -n -v" in your question ?

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Comment: I don't see anything concerning the established connections in your firewall in INPUT. So you will not receive the packets from the outside. You must add a log at the end and check your logs to debug your firewall

Comment: Could you post the command?

Comment: Could you do the command when the firewall is active and filtering, not disabled :-)

Comment: Should now be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your firewall is missing major part.
The first packet go to outside correctely (as the OUTPUT policy is ACCEPT).
The fist incoming packet is rejected as there is nothing allow in INPUT rule.
You should have a `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` to allow the connection tracking to allow the packet to come.
The second packet will be allowed to go out too as the OUTPUT policy is ACCEPT.

Add a rule to log what is reject is important. 
Add `iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "DROP4 INPUT "` at the end of the INPUT rule.

A remark : do you need all the opened ports in INPUT ? The mysql service opened to Internet is not really a good idea...

Comment: In my Firewall, I only allow MySQL, SSH and others to be opened in the IP subnet of my servers. Everyone outside will is blocked.

Comment: Oh wait, it doesn't! Thanks for letting me know. I will edit that now. A huge thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow incoming packets, related to your outgoing connections.

```
iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

If that doesn't work:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Differences are discussed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108169/what-is-the-difference-between-m-conntrack-ctstate-and-m-state-state

Answer (score 0):

basvdlei & Dom is answer is right,

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

but, wget or apt need one more thing: DNS
add below line works fine in my situation

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53  -j ACCEPT
```